# Should ntpd must listen on 192.168.1.255 interface?

Tags: 16.04, ntp

ntpd configured for listen only on local interface:

```
interface ignore 0.0.0.0
interface ignore 192.168.1.255

interface listen br-enp3s0
interface listen 127.0.0.1
```

but netstat reports another:

```
netstat -lnp46 | grep ntpd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.255:123     0.0.0.0:*                           2981/ntpd       
udp        0      0 192.168.1.2:123       0.0.0.0:*                           2981/ntpd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123         0.0.0.0:*                           2981/ntpd
```

Why `192.168.1.255` is adding to listen to ?

On `precise` and `trusty` this does not happen.

Comment: Do you have a line with `broadcastclient` in your ntp.conf?

Comment: NTPD_OPTS  contained `-b` flag in `/etc/default/ntp`. Removing this parameter fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You should write an answer to your own post to explain it to others, who may find this in a future search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NTPD_OPTS` contained `-b` flag in `/etc/default/ntp`. Removing this parameter fixed the issue.

Check you distro service init script/settings, if config does not use broadcast setting.

The broadcast and multicast modes are inherently less accurate and less secure. See explain [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/444777/when-should-ntpd-broadcast-broadcastclient-be-used-instead-of-client-server-or-p)